# Modelar un diagrama E-R

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

estoy apenas aprendiendo sobre el mundo de las bases de datos para aprovechar el tiempo en cuarentena.

En internet encontré el siguiente ejercicio del 2012 (https://www.yumpu.com/es/document/read/18191834/elementos-de-bases-de-datos-ejercicios-departamento-de-):

Considera la entidad Equipo con el atributo NombreEquipo, la entidad Jugador con el atributo NombreJugador y la entidad Camiseta con el atributo Número. Obtén un diagrama E-R que modele la siguiente información:

Un equipo debe está formado por muchos jugadores y cada jugador puede integrarse a un solo equipo.

En cada equipo hay muchos números de camiseta. El mismo número de camiseta puede ser utilizado en
diferentes equipos, pero dentro de un equipo no hay dos números de camiseta iguales.

Cada jugador debe tener asignado un único número de camiseta en el equipo que integre.

Y esto es lo que llevo por el momento:

El problema es que no sé muy bien como hacer que el mismo número de camiseta puede ser utilizado en diferentes equipos, pero dentro de un equipo no hay dos números de camiseta iguales y también si debería de asignar atributos llave a las entidades o no.

Answer (score 3):

A mi entender ese diagrama ER resuleve aunque no este normalizado aún. Lo ideal en el caso en el que tenes relaciones muchos a muchos (Muchos Jugadores tienen muchos numeros y Muchos numeros son compartidos por muchos jugadores) es normalizar creando una tabla intermedia por ejemplo **CamisetaPorJugador** y es esta tabla la que tendra una camiseta y tendra un jugador.

La PK de esta tabla será conformada por la PK de Jugador y la PK de Camiseta. Es decir que la PK está integrada por 2 FK y es ésta convinacion de FK la que no se repite en toda la tabla **CamisetaPorJugador**.